# Generate Array from a comma-separated list - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a variable defined like so: **$var = "1, 2, 3";**  & I have an array: **$thePostIdArray = array(1, 2, 3);**

The Array above works great when looping through it but when I try to use the **$var** in place of the comma-separated list, problems occur.

So (perfect world) it could be **$thePostIdArray = array($var);** which would be the same as **$thePostIdArray = array(1, 2, 3);**.

*Every attempt so far hasn't worked :'(*

**Is this even possible, or is there an easier workaround?**

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: If php had that logic you expect, I'd be driven mad :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Check out [`explode`](http://php.net/explode): `$thePostIdArray = explode(', ', $var);`

Answer (score 5):

use explode function. this will solve your problem. 
structure of explode is like this

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

now `$delimiter`
is the boundary string, `string $string` is the input string.
for limit:

If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last -limit are returned.

If the limit parameter is zero, then this is treated as 1.

visit the following link. you can learn best from that
[link of php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 2):

For developer who wants result with `and` in the end can use the following code:

```
$titleString = array('apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'grape');
$totalTitles = count($titleString);
if($totalTitles>1)
{
    $titleString = implode(', ' , array_slice($titleString,0,$totalTitles-1)) . ' and ' . end($titleString);
}
else
{
    $titleString = implode(', ' , $titleString);
}

echo $titleString; // apple, banana, pear and grape
```